# Can't seem to nest php variable inside shortcode

Tags: nested, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I've had a look at various StackOverflow questions but still can't seem to find a successful way to use a variable inside a shortcode. The code in question is as follows (the variable I'm trying to insert into the shortcode is `$track_audio`.

```
    <?php
        $track_audio = get_sub_field('mp3_url');

        $renderedShortcode = do_shortcode('[fusion_audio src=". $track_audio . loop="off"][/fusion_audio]');

        echo $renderedShortcode; ?>
```

I've read a fair few conversations on Stackoverflow but have not found a solution that works. The last idea i tried was to concatenate the variable (see code) but that hasn't worked either. Is anyone able to tell me the correct way to do this?

Many thanks in advance for your help with this

Phil

Comment: Ok having tried various ways, it seems there was a mistake in my coding and by closing the single ticks before the variable & opening the single ticks after it, the code worked correctly - like so . . . `do_shortcode( ' [fusion_audio src=" ' . $track_audio . ' loop="off"][/fusion_audio] ' );` Apologies

Answer (score 0):

Try this way working for me

Change code from

```
$renderedShortcode = do_shortcode('[fusion_audio src=". $track_audio . loop="off"][/fusion_audio]');
```

TO

```
 $renderedShortcode = do_shortcode('[fusion_audio src="'.$track_audio.'" loop="off"][/fusion_audio]');
```

Final conclision:

```
$track_audio = get_sub_field('mp3_url');
$renderedShortcode = do_shortcode('[fusion_audio src="'.$track_audio.'" loop="off"][/fusion_audio]');
echo $renderedShortcode; 


function fusion_audio_shortcode_func( $atts, $content = null ) {

      extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
           'loop' => '',
            ), $atts )
    );


    $loop; 


   return '<awesomeness>' . $content . '</awesomeness>';
}

add_shortcode( 'fusion_audio', 'fusion_audio_shortcode_func' );
```